# Error running npm start for expo app I think it is due to sudo

Tags: node.js, npm, expo, sudo

I am trying to run my application but I can only run it while using "sudo npm start," which I think is affecting the build of my app in expo. I believe my problem will go away when I am able to run "npm start," but as of now, when I run this I get the following error:

```
> @ start /Users/ryanfay/csc308outdoors
> expo start

Uncaught Error [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/ryanfay/.expo/state.json.725563943'] {
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/Users/ryanfay/.expo/state.json.725563943'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ryanfay/.npm/_logs/2020-05-20T02_01_41_168Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

The file the app is trying to use probably belong to another user. It can happen if at some point you ran `sudo npm start`, then any file created will belong to the root user.

You can change ownership back to your user with `sudo chown -R ryanfay /Users/ryanfay/.expo`.